# How to generate one services.xml with multiple wsdl files

Tags: java, soap, wsdl, apache-axis

I am newbie to Axis. Currently everything works with one wsdl. We use axis to create services.xml.

Now I am creating a new wsdl file under a different namespace. How can I generate a single services.xml file using these two wsdl files?

What I want to achieve is that both SOAP services bind to one port.

By the way, I am using ant to build the project.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

We use an ant `concat` rule like the following:

```
    <concat destfile="/some/final/services.xml" fixlastline="yes">
        <file file="/first/services.xml" />
        <file file="/second/services.xml" />
        <filterchain><tokenfilter>
            <filetokenizer />
            <replaceregex
                 pattern="&lt;/serviceGroup&gt;.+?&lt;serviceGroup&gt;"
                 flags="gs" />
            <replaceregex
                pattern="first.default.service.class"
                replace="first.actual.service.class" />
            <replaceregex
                pattern="second.default.service.class"
                replace="second.actual.service.class" />
        </tokenfilter></filterchain>
    </concat>
```

This concatenates the source files (the two `<file...>` elements) into the destination file (the `destfile` attribute). The `<filterchain>` section allows you to change the text during the concatenation. The first `replaceregex` here removes the `</servicegroup><servicegroup>` tags from the points where two files are concatenated. Other `replaceregex` entries can be used to change the names of the service implementation classes, add a service lifecycle class entry, or to make other changes.

In some of our projects, the original `services.xml` files are stored within a zipfile or jarfile instead of directly in the filesystem. For that you'd use a `<zipentry...>` element rather than a `<file...>` element:

```
<zipentry zipfile="/some/jarfile.jar" name="resources/services.xml"/>
```